# make pop up alert confirm on php

Tags: database, codeigniter, model-view-controller, popup

I want to make a popup alert when I will delete items, but I use `echo`, I only understand using `a href`

I want alike this

```
<a href="<?=base_url('index.php/buku/hapus/'.$i->kode_buku)?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are  you sure?')">
```

and I want to give that feature to the code below

```
<?php echo anchor ('barang/delete/'.$u->kode_barang,'Hapus') ; ?>
```

but where and how do I add it to the php program? do I need to add something to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#anchor

```
$array = array(
    'class' => 'btn',
    'onclick' => "return confirm('Are  you sure?');",
);

echo anchor('someurl/here', 'Name', $array);
```

although to me it's better to do the first way and seems less verbose. just because the function exists doesn't mean you have to use it.

Comment: make sense, but im still struggle to make the pop up. thanks anyway

Comment: i believe I answered your question, you wanted to know how to convert a to b and this is how you do it.  this code works and generates a return confirmation on click.